# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm using `templateRest` to post `User` object to `Rest Server` but I encoutered the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException    at
>   edu.java.spring.service.client.RestClientTest.main(RestClientTest.java:33)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 1 more

Here is the file `RestClientTest.java`

```
public class RestClientTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
//      System.out.println("Rest Response" + loadUser("quypham"));
//      URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/rest/user/create");
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
//      Map<String,String> vars = new HashMap<String,String>();

        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName("datpham");
        user.setPassWord("12345");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,1960);
        user.setBirthDay(calendar.getTime());
        user.setAge(12);
        String uri = new String("http://localhost:8080/rest/user/create");
        User returns = rt.postForObject(uri, user,User.class);

//      createUser(user);
        System.out.println("Rest Response" + loadUser("datpham"));
    }
```

Here is the file `UserRestServiceController.java`

```
@Controller
public class UserRestServiceController {
    @Autowired
    public  UserDao userDao;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/user/create",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userDao.save(user);
    }
```

Here is the file pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.java.spring.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>springDAT-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springDAT-service Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springMOTHER-service</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2524m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1048m -Xms536m
                        -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>lib</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/spring-mvc/WEB-INF/lib</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

I have browsed information on google, afterwards I have tried to add jackson 2.4 in pom.xml but didn't seem to work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-rc3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 12):

Add this :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You can replace `${jackson.version}` with any version you want,or just add  `<jackson.version>2.x.x</jackson.version>`at top of your pom.xml

p/s:Mine is version `2.7.3`

Comment: i add this dependencies in pom.xml. after i mvn jetty:run then occur error:`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project springDAT-service: Could not resolve d
ependencies for project edu.java.spring.service:springDAT-service:war:1.0-SNAPSH
OT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:ja
r:2.7.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jacks
on-core:jar:2.7.3:`

Comment: `Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackso
n-core:pom:2.7.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\REPO\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\
2.7.3\jackson-core-2.7.3.pom.part.lock (The system cannot find the path specifie
d) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Do you update maven after that? Right click project->Maven->Update Project and press ok.

Comment: Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jac
kson-core/2.7.3/jackson-core-2.7.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Program Files
 (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\REPO\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.7.3\jac
kson-core-2.7.3.pom.lastUpdated

Comment: that because you put it in windows directory, you should put it in .m2 repository under user profile,and that should work. Change your maven setting at settings.xml

Comment: i have changed locate maven, everything run ok, thank you more :))))

Comment: Gud luk, you can accept my answer so it can help everyone else :)

Comment: after modifying pom.xml, mvn dependency:resolve  can be used to update.

Answer (score -2):

Try add to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have tried with your way, but still occur similar error.

Comment: This does not help, I have jackson-core-asl already, without success. The JsonProcessingException in jackson-core-asl is in another package: org.codehaus.jackson.