# JWT create method return an error in Java app

Tags: java, jersey, jwt

In my Java application I'm trying to create a JWT token. Here's how I trying to do that.

```
            HashMap<String, String> auth = new HashMap<String, String>();
            auth.put("user_id", Long.toString(user_id));
            auth.put("username", username);
            auth.put("role", role);

            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret");
            String token = JWT.create()
                  .withIssuer("medi-care-rest-api")
                  .withSubject("medi-care-rest-api-jwt")
                  .withAudience("medicare.com")
                  .withClaim("user", auth)
                  .sign(algorithm);
```

But I'm getting below error,

```
threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
```

So I download the jackson core jar file and add to the build path. ( I'm not using Maven ) but still I get this error.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: This might sound stupid but are you sure that the downloaded jar is actually present in the latest build... sometimes it happens that compiled build (war/jar) has not yet picked the jars in their classpath.. mostly due to caching in IDEs.  (I don't know how you are doing it exactly.. so just guessing)

Comment: You can try running your app by providing the classpath jar in run command if you are not sure about the downloaded jar.

Comment: @miiiii thank you for the comment. I'm pretty sure it's present in the latest build. I'm using eclipse. I can see the jar in the build path library list. I also try to restart the IDE and remove the server and recreate everything from start, but still I'm getting this error. I have downloaded jackson-core-2.11.0.jar file.

Comment: To be frank.. I don't know where u r using Jackson.. but can you also download all these 3 jars from this maven repo and put in classpath/build path and try?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36279872/6446770

Comment: I did. I have added all the three jar files. I really don't want to use Jackson. I just want to Sign and verify JWT tokens. I added the JWT library and trying to use it but when the application run `jwt.create()` it throws this `classNotFound` error

Comment: Can you tell me which jwt library you are using? Are your JWT imports coming from this package `com.auth0.jwt` ?

Comment: I'm using this one https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

Comment: I can see in jwt jar that https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.10.3/jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar is required at runtime. It is not provided within the jar. It should have worked if you are doing it correctly. I still doubt that your build path is not correct or it is ignored.

I can't help beyond this.. or else.. can you share your project on github/gitlab so that I may reproduce and tell u the solution.

Comment: @miiiii Oh I forgot to tell you. Today I create a new project and added jar files and src code to it and then build the project. For some reason error was gone and then I received a new error which is another class not found exception. So I just download the jar and added it and clear project and build again but still not working. Then I create another new project and past everything build again.

Comment: Then it worked but I cannot do that every time. I cannot add Maven to the project, too. This one is a University project and other members don't know to use it. So looks like I have to do this every time I add external jar file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213559/discussion-between-miiiii-and-dilshan).